# Auto HTML for population from URL or script

Tags: html, forms, submit

I uave to enter a registration my car reg on https://www.parkinggenie.co.uk/82679 every time I visit.

I have inspected the code attached.

I am trying to create either a script or the url command that submits everything in one go so i can just click the URL once.  is that possible?

either the URL i need to enter, or how to pass a script

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.